# Having trouble using VLOOKUP() with multiple worksheets and multiple inputs

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I'm trying to set up a quick way to pull data based off two inputs.

The inputs are on the first worksheet, `Journey`. The first input, `C2`, is a dropdown list where the selections are the same as the titles of worksheets 3-11. The second input, `N2`, is a number from 1 to 100.

On worksheets 3-11 are tables with two columns. Column `A` contains a number from 1 to 100 (which will be matched with the inputted value in `N2`). Column `B` contains the information I need to pull out for `O2` in `Journey`.

Is there a formula that can look at `C2`, find that worksheet, and use `N2` to find the information needed, and pull that information back to `Journey`?

Here are the screenshots of the `Journey` worksheet

[image: Journey Worksheet Screenshot]

and one of the worksheets 3-11

[image: Worksheets 3-11 Screenshot]

I have tried to use the `INDIRECT()` and the `INDEX()`/`MATCH()` functions but could not get them to work.

If more information is needed please ask and I will add it.

Comment: A picture is worth 1000 words.  People don't have your workbook in front of them.  You'll get a better response if you show what the worksheets look like and the result you want.

Comment: better you post some sample data & the formula you are using, will help us to fix the issue.

Comment: I have added some images and hopefully a better explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INDIRECT()` to compile a string representing the correct range to run the lookup on like so:

```
=VLOOKUP(N2,INDIRECT("'"&C2&"'!A:B"),2,FALSE)
```

.

### Some explanation

```
"'"&C2&"'!A:B"
```

`C2` contains the name of the worksheet to run the lookup on. `&` is the concatenation operator. Values in double quotes (`"`) are strings. If `C2` = `"Orange"` then the concatenated string would be `"'Orange'!A:B"`.

```
INDIRECT("'"&C2&"'!A:B")
```

`INDIRECT()` simply takes the name of a range in string format and returns a reference to that range. So given `"'Orange'!A:B"`, `INDIRECT()` will return a reference to the range `'Orange'!A:B`. We can then pass this to `VLOOKUP()` as its second parameter (as shown above).

Comment: I spent several hours trying to look at help videos and tutorials for the INDIRECT but I could not get it to work. I added a couple of images and hopefully a better explanation. @Cliff

Comment: @BrianLehman Just copy paste the first formula in this answer, i.e. `=VLOOKUP(N2,INDIRECT("'"&C2&"'!A:B"),2,FALSE)`, into cell `O2`, and then fill the formula down. It works perfectly. I'm not sure what you don't understand.

Comment: @robinCTS I did just that and I get #REF!

Comment: @robinCTS  wanted to let you know I had a friend take a look at it and the formula was correct. The problem was on the title of the tab Coast. I accidentally hit the space bar before typing. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: @BrianLehman Only just woke up ;-) Glad you got it sorted out. If you'd followed the instructions fully, even after receiving the error, you'd have seen that the other cells in column `O` would have worked ;-) Oh,well. Next time. Don't forgot to accept the answer by clicking on the grey tick at the top-left of the answer.